# Error while starting WSO2 ISKM 5.10.0 server in fully distributed WSO2 APIM setup

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I am configuring WSO2 fully distributed platform and I have configured two WSO2 ISKM servers using the below database configurations.

```
[user_store]
type = "database_unique_id"

[database.apim_db]
type = "mysql"
url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/apim_db"
username = "apimadmin"
password = "apimadmin"

[database.shared_db]
type = "mysql"
url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shared_db"
username = "regadmin"
password = "regadmin"
```

But this configuration returns the following error in the second server.

```
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Using sql : INSERT INTO UM_SYSTEM_USER_ROLE (UM_USER_NAME, UM_ROLE_ID, UM_TENANT_ID) VALUES (?,(SELECT UM_ID FROM UM_SYSTEM_ROLE WHERE UM_ROLE_NAME=? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?), ?) Duplicate entry 'wso2.anonymous.user-1--1234' for key 'UM_USER_NAME'
```

Then I changed the DB configuration as below,

```
[user_store]
type = "database"
```

Here both servers started, but cannot log into the management console with admin, admin credentials. It shows as incorrect username password. How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked with the DB configuration

```
[user_store]
type = "database_unique_id"
```

after clearing the data in `UM_SYSTEM_USER_ROLE` table and restart the servers.